# Storing data in variable from a closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

My purpose for this code is to store a variable from a closure in a global variable, with this code I'd like to store jsonResponse.data to aa, but each time outside the closure aa is nil, it seems logic but is there a way to persist this variable outside the closure ?

Thanks for your help

My code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myJson:NSDictionary?
    var aa:Any?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url="https://mastodon.cloud/api/v1/apps"

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["client_name": "Coucou", "redirect_uris": "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "scopes": "read"]).responseJSON { (jsonResponse) in
            if jsonResponse.error != nil{
                print("error \(jsonResponse.error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }
            print(jsonResponse.data!)
            self.aa=jsonResponse.data!
        }
        print(aa) // return nil !!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but your code executes in wrong order. The "print" is executed before the closure, so "nil" is correct.

If you call "print(aa)" after the closure is finished it is set correctly.

```
  print(jsonResponse.data!)
  self.aa=jsonResponse.data!
  print(self.aa) // should work
}
```

Comment: he is calling print(aa) after closure only

Comment: The Alamofire.request closure is an async call .. so its execute after print @SanketBhavsar

Comment: I know but Id' like to store my response from the closure to a class variable, is it possible ?

Comment: sure .. it is done ... only you print the value at the wrong moment

Comment: @OliverM understood what you are saying.

Comment: No .. as long as your ViewController exists. Try printing the value in another closure that is executed after the requests is completed